# What's the state of cross-browser support for DOM Mutation Observers?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mutation-observers

I [googled](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=dom+mutation+observers+support&oq=dom+mutation+observers+support&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...69.32879.0.32981.37.32.2.0.0.0.326.6714.2-27j3.30.0...0.0.xsxdy9m5QyQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=6fe1c4b9df5a02ef&ion=1&biw=1440&bih=712) but couldn't find an answer.

Is there a cross-browser compatibility matrix available for this feature?

In case anybody wants to know the answer, here it is: [Mutation Observers vs Mutation Events/Browser Availability](http://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/wiki/DOMMutationObservers#Browser_Availability).

Comment: Define _"this feature"_ please. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature (DOM mutation) is working from Chrome 18.
You can see more details here: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers

In case you wish to check 'any' HTML5 feature and the browsers that support it: http://caniuse.com/ is the place.
Other great source is: http://html5please.com/

Comment: (So, in addition to the links, provide a summary and/or excerpts as relevant.)

Comment: It seems to work in iOS 6 though the article doesn't mention it!

Comment: Neither of those sites lists browser support for Mutation Observers.

Comment: Here's a caniuse link to save extra clicks [http://caniuse.com/mutationobserver](http://caniuse.com/mutationobserver)

Answer (score 10):

Ido Green provided the answer, but for clarity I will post relevant snippets of the linked docs here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events

> DOM Mutation Events are now deprecated.
>
> The mutation events have been marked as deprecated in the DOM Events specification, as the API's design is flawed (see details in the "DOM Mutation Events Replacement: The Story So Far / Existing Points of Consensus" post to public-webapps).
>
> The practical reasons to avoid the mutation events are performance issues and cross-browser support.
>
> These are being replaced by DOM Mutation Observers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver

> Mutation Observers provides developers a way to react to changes in a DOM. It is designed as a replacement for Mutation Events defined in the DOM3 Events specification.
>
> - [A brief overview](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers)
> - [A more in-depth discussion](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)
> - [A screencast by Chromium developer Rafael Weinstein](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRZ4pO0gVWw)
> - [The mutation summary library](http://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/)
> - [The DOM4 specification](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutation-observers) which defines the `MutationObserver` interface