# Detecting attribute change of value of an attribute I made

Tags: jquery, html

I created an attribute in HTML `data-select-content-val` and it is stuffed with information dynamically.

Is there a way to detect when the attribute's value has changed?

```
$(document).on("change", "div[data-select-content-val]", function(){
    alert("BOOP!");
});
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You would have to watch the DOM node changes. There is an API called [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but it looks like the support for it is very limited. This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10966864/328555) has a link to the [status](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/wiki/DOMMutationObservers#Browser_Availability) of the API, but it seems like there is no support for it in IE or Opera so far.

One way you could get around this problem is to have the part of the code that modifies the `data-select-content-val` attribute dispatch an event that you can listen to.

For example, see: http://jsbin.com/arucuc/3/edit on how to tie it together.

The code here is

```
$(function() {  
  // Here you register for the event and do whatever you need to do.
  $(document).on('data-attribute-changed', function() {
    var data = $('#contains-data').data('mydata');
    alert('Data changed to: ' + data);
  });

  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('#contains-data').data('mydata', 'foo');
    // Whenever you change the attribute you will user the .trigger
    // method. The name of the event is arbitrary
    $(document).trigger('data-attribute-changed');
  });

   $('#getbutton').click(function() {
    var data = $('#contains-data').data('mydata');
    alert('Data is: ' + data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Wait so your answer is don't detect but rather trigger an event when it on a click? Hmmm

Comment: i wonder why the designers of HTML decided not to support "onattributechange". It is possible to create your own event model on top of HTML, but if it is done, then you need to prohibit direct manipulation of DOM without issuing an event alongside it(eg, if you change checked property of a checkbox, you must also issue an event that you changed the checked property to the window), allowing the event model to behave correctly, but this breaks a lot of existing modules that depend on direct dom mutation, and leaves room of difficult to find bugs due to forgetting to issue an event..

Answer (score 29):

You can use [MutationObserver](http://www.javascripture.com/MutationObserver) to track attribute changes including `data-*` changes.  For example:

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log('data-select-content-val changed');
});
observer.observe(foo, { 
  attributes: true, 
  attributeFilter: ['data-select-content-val'] });

foo.dataset.selectContentVal = 1;
```

```html
 <div id='foo'></div>
```

Comment: dude, that's a really cool answer, i really like that more than the jquery approach, it's a really good answer, thanks for sharing

Comment: @nkron simple and elegant, love it!

Answer (score 11):

There is [this](https://github.com/meetselva/attrchange) extensions that adds an event listener to attribute changes.

Usage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/meetselva/attrchange/master/js/attrchange.js"></script>
```

Bind attrchange handler function to selected elements

```
$(selector).attrchange({
    trackValues: true, /* Default to false, if set to true the event object is 
                updated with old and new value.*/
    callback: function (event) { 
        //event               - event object
        //event.attributeName - Name of the attribute modified
        //event.oldValue      - Previous value of the modified attribute
        //event.newValue      - New value of the modified attribute
        //Triggered when the selected elements attribute is added/updated/removed
    }        
});
```

Comment: FYI the second script gives a "Not Found"

Comment: This link works: https://cdn.rawgit.com/meetselva/attrchange/master/js/attrchange.js

Comment: That solution crashes firefox and edge because observers aren't supported.

Comment: Is there a possibility to detect a source of change (i.e. line of code which caused the change) ?