# onchange event for attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

**html:**

```
<input class="spinner1 ui-spinner-input" id="q1" name="value" value="1" min="1" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuenow="5" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton">
```

how to add an event on changing value of `aria-valuenow`?

Comment: What makes `aria-valuenow` attribute to change?

Comment: Hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781778/detecting-attribute-change-of-value-of-an-attribute-i-made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Native way that is supported by all browsers to do this, you can check a look on [Mutation_Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) but it is not fully functional.

You can though, trigger a custom event on the item that is changing you custom attribute, and listen to this event to make needed changes :

```
$(document).on('custom-attribute-changes', function() {
    // listen to the data change and do what you need
  });

  $('#button').click(function() {

// trigger this event on any certain change that shall edit its value
    $(document).trigger('custom-attribute-changes');
  });
```