# Detect changes in DOM properties

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know there is a way to detect changes in HTML attributes, DOM node subtree, etc. However, I could not find a way to detect a change in the node property, such as  `offsetParent` of the certain div. This information tells me whether that div is displayed on the screen. So, if `offsetParent` has the value of `null`, it means that div is stil not visible on the page. I have tried with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), [Object.prototype.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch), but with no success.

Does enyone find the solution? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect change in a property of DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787689/how-to-detect-change-in-a-property-of-dom)

Comment: No, it isn't a duplicate. There is an important difference. Other questions do not address changes in node properties.