# detect data- on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to change value of div when data attr of another div will change. I'm trying to do that

```
$('.language-rate').attr("data-rate-value").on('change', function () {
    $('.language-d').text($('.language-rate').attr("data-rate-value"));
});
```

but it logs in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

How can I do that?

my view is:

```
               @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LanguagesTable", new AjaxOptions()
                {
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    UpdateTargetId = "languages"
                }))
                {
                    <div class="language-content">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.newLanguages.LanguageName, new { @class = "pcontent-left main-color" })
                        <div class="rate language-rate"></div>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.newLanguages.Star, new { @class = "language-d" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="add-education">
                        <button type="submit" name="pcprograms" value="add" class="add-education-button-sm">add</button>
                    </div>
                }
```

I'm using [rater js](http://auxiliary.github.io/rater/) and when star rate changes i want to detect and pass in my model (which is hidden form controll)

**EDITED**

I'm doing that:

```
$('.language-rate').on('change', function () {
    $('.language-d').text($('.language-rate').attr("data-rate-value"));
});
```

but it works after second click on div. because i want to detect attribute change event

Comment: share html as well and clarify what you want to do and what to expect.like how will the data attr of that another div change?

Comment: @guradio I'm using rater js. It's complex html (asp.net mvc razor) and because didn't post it

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781778/detecting-attribute-change-of-value-of-an-attribute-i-made

Comment: The `.on()` method is available on jQuery objects, but you're calling it on the return value of `.attr()`, which will either be `undefined` or a string. The `'change'` event that you're trying to use applies to DOM elements (form elements), not to element attributes.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm trying `change` too but it works after second click.

Comment: @user3297291 tried that but not helped..

Comment: @nnnnnn I've edited my question. see **edited** section

Comment: The `'change'` event is triggered by changes to a form element's value, not by changes to an element's attributes. Does the rater.js library that you're using trigger any events (custom events, perhaps) when the rating is updated?

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah it changes data-rate-value attribute of my `.language-rate` class

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot hook an event onto a data attribute.There are a lot of posts about this on SO and other sources.What you can do is create a function which runs often (e.g. every 200 milliseconds) and checks if the the value of the data attribute of your div has changed.Here's an example, i hope it helps you:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var _old = $("#test").attr('data-value');

        setInterval(function () {
            var _new = $("#test").attr('data-value');

            if(_old != _new)
            {
                alert('The data attribute of the div has been changed to - ' + _new);
                _old = _new;
            }

        }, 200);

        $("#changeData").click(function () {
            $("#test").attr('data-value',new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
        });

    });
</script>
<div id="test" data-value="Test">
</div>
<input type="button" id="changeData" value="Change Data Attribute" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This question still ranks high if you're looking for DOM change handling.

Nowadays you can use pretty performant classes like `MutationObserver`

You can easily hook into the change of `data-rate_value` with the following code snippet:

```js
// fake data attribute change
const node = document.getElementById("example")

const set_to_five = () => {
  node.dataset["rate_value"] = "5"
}

const set_to_one = () => {
  node.dataset["rate_value"] = "1"
}

// continuously change data attribute
setInterval(() => {
  set_to_five()

  setTimeout(set_to_one, 2500)
}, 5000)

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    console.log(mutation);
  });
})

observer.observe(node, {
  attributes: true, // this can be omitted
  attributeFilter: ["data-rate_value"]
});
```

```html
<div id="example" style="background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
```