# Is there an event to detect if an attribute is set in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events

I want to execute a script when some data attribute are set. Attributes can be set AFTER the all page is loaded.

In that case the script doesn't execute.

```
<div data-id='' data-position=''></div>
```

But in that one, i want to execute it

```
<div data-id='3' data-position='67'></div>
```

Is it even possible ?

Comment: If your script is assigning the value/attribute, execute required things after assignment..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting attribute change of value of an attribute I made](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781778/detecting-attribute-change-of-value-of-an-attribute-i-made)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen attribute change and act upon.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the attributes of html means that it is done programmatically via jQuery as in:

`$("div").attr("data-id", "someId");`

So if it is your script performing this action then simply do whatever you want right after.

If you want to check if the attribute has been set you can do:

`if ( $("div").attr("data-id") != "" ) { do the stuff you want }`

If you want to listen to changes then go for @Jaganathan's suggestion