# Custom div attribute catch changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with custom attribute `posx`

```
<div class="js__scroll__canvas" posx="0">
```

Another js plugin set dynamic value to posx on scroll.

I try to catch `posx` is change.

```
$(".js__scroll__canvas").attr( "posx" ).change(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

Nothing alerts. How to catch it? Help please

Comment: Please make sure you included jquery library or not? And another thing in console any error occurs?

Comment: in your html i will see the class js__scroll but you used in the jquery codes js__scroll__canvas. Please check it first

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, but doesn't work, js library is on, nothing errors.

Comment: You may find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781778/detecting-attribute-change-of-value-of-an-attribute-i-made)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with setting up an event and triggering it while data gets updated. Please check below snippet if it can help you.

```js
//Set up an event
$(".js__scroll__canvas").on('datachange', function(e, key){
     alert( "Handler for .datachange() called." );
});

// Then trigger it when you data gets updated 
$(".js__scroll__canvas").data('posx', 123).trigger('datachange');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js__scroll__canvas" posx="0">
```

Comment: In your case, as it is changing dynamically, you can trigger it on scroll event I guess.

Comment: Is it possibility to change (e, key) to (ev, key), or (event, key)

Comment: Yes, you can change it to any text.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="js__scroll__canvas" posx="0">
```

`$(".js__scroll__canvas").attr( "posx" )` return a string `"0"`. So, it cannot be used as a selector to call [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) method.

If you want to log, try to create a function:

```
var logging = function () {
    console.log('the attribute has been changed.');
};

var dowork = function () {
    // try to update attribute    
    $(".js__scroll__canvas").attr( "posx", "1" );

    // logging
    logging();
};
```