# Catch on change of prop disable Jquery

Tags: javascript, properties, triggers, onchange

How can I catch change of button's prop (to disabled)?

I have 3rd party js running and after its finished it turns button to disable. Problem is that my code added dynamically (as well as button itself)

My code is:

```
$(document).on('change', '.stripe-button-el', function(){
console.log('changed');
if ($($this).prop('disabled', true)) $('.stripe-btn-wrapper').trigger('submit');
})
```

Not firing. But if I change it to on ('click'..) I see log.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: i think you need to see and read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781778/detecting-attribute-change-of-value-of-an-attribute-i-made

Comment: I'll check. Thanks. Never saw data-atribute-change before..